# Is there an infix version for routine invocation in perl 6?

Tags: functional-programming, raku

Say I want to apply an array of functions to an array of objects. Something like this:

```
my $a = sub ($) { $_ * 2 };
my $b = sub ($) { $_ / 2 };

my @funcs = ($a, $b);

my @ops = @funcs.roll(4);
```

I could do

```
say  ^10 ».&» @ops;
```

but [`.&` is a postfix operator](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#postfix_.&); same thing for [>>.](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#postfix_%C2%BB._/_postfix_%3E%3E.), which could be used for a single function, however. Using

```
say  ^10 Z. @ops;
```

with `.` actually being the infix operator for calling a method, yields an error about mistaking it for the concatenation operator. I don't think I have any other option left. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `&infix:« o »` / `&infix:« ∘ »` operator, combined with a lambda/closure factory.

```perl6
sub lambda-factory ( +in ) {
  in.map: -> \_ { ->{_} }
}

my @funcs = (
  * * 2,
  * / 2
);

(@funcs X∘ lambda-factory ^10)».()
# (0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5)

(@funcs «∘» lambda-factory ^10)».()
# [0, 0.5, 4, 1.5, 8, 2.5, 12, 3.5, 16, 4.5]

( (|@funcs xx *) Z∘ lambda-factory ^10 )».()
# (0, 0.5, 4, 1.5, 8, 2.5, 12, 3.5, 16, 4.5)
```

Comment: No easier way to do that? If I got that correctly, you are building a pointy block out of the arguments to be able to apply the function to them, right? OK; I see, you are creating a new function out of the arguments and applying them... right.

Answer (score 4):

If you have defined values, you can use the infix operator [`andthen`.](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#infix_andthen)

```perl6
    say (^10 »andthen» (* * 2, * / 2).roll(4))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you roll your own infix equivalent of .& the construct you are trying to create seems to work fine.

```
$ perl6 -e 'my sub infix:<foo> ($a, $b) { $b($a) }; say ^10 Z[foo] (-> $_ { $_*2 }, -> $_ { $_/2 }).roll(4);'
(0 0.5 1 6)
```